# Need help with Subquery in parent-child relationship query

Tags: soql, query, filters, parent-to-child

I have a query where I have to query contacts and their cases only if case `status != "Completed" or "Pending"`. But in my Parent-child query, cases are getting retrieved irrespective of the filter on status.

```
select id,Casedeletedcontact__c,(select id,status__c from cases1__r where status__c!='Completed' or status__c!='Pending') from contact
```

[image]

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong operator here. You don't want `OR`, you want `AND`.

Reason being is that if status is 'Pending', it'll satisfy the `!= 'Completed'` bit and thus get returned in your subquery (`true || false` = `true`)

When you use `AND` though, both parts need to be satisfied for the result to be true (and for the child row to be returned). Since the 'Pending' and 'Completed' statuses can only ever satisfy one of those two filters, rows with those statuses will not be included. (`true && false` = `false`)